# Convert hexadecimal number to double

Tags: php, hex

The string of the hexadecimal  number is like: 0X1.05P+10

The real value of this hexadecimal  number is:1044.0

I can convert it using C language with method strtod.
But I can't find the way to convert it in PHP. Can somebody show me how to do it?

value string list:

```
1. "0X1.FAP+9"
2. "0X1.C4P+9"
3. "0X1.F3P+9"
4. "0X1.05P+10"
```

Comment: man strtod :A  hexadecimal  number  consists  of a ''0x'' or ''0X'' followed by a nonempty sequence of hexadecimal digits possibly containing a
       radix character, optionally followed by a binary exponent. A binary exponent consists of a ''P'' or ''p'', followed by an  optional
       plus or minus sign, followed by a non-empty sequence of decimal digits, and indicates multiplication by a power of 2.  At least one
       of radix character and binary exponent must be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to make a custom function for this. So  because I'm feeling nice today I custom-made one for you:

```
function strtod($hex) {
    preg_match('#([\da-f]+)\.?([\da-f]*)p#i', $hex, $parts);

    $i = 0;
    $fractional_part = array_reduce(str_split($parts[2]), function($sum, $part) use (&$i) {
        $sum += hexdec($part) * pow(16, --$i);

        return $sum;
    });

    $decimal = (hexdec($parts[1]) + $fractional_part) * pow(2, array_pop(explode('+', $hex)));  

    return $decimal;
}

foreach(array('0X1.FAP+9', '0X1.C4P+9', '0X1.F3P+9', '0X1.05P+10', '0X1P+0') as $hex) {
    var_dump(strtod($hex));
};
```

For versions below PHP 5.3:

```
function strtod($hex) {
    preg_match('#([\da-f]+)\.?([\da-f]*)p#i', $hex, $parts);

    $fractional_part = 0;

    foreach(str_split($parts[2]) as $index => $part) {
        $fractional_part += hexdec($part) * pow(16, ($index + 1) * -1);
    }

    $decimal = (hexdec($parts[1]) + $fractional_part) * pow(2, array_pop(explode('+', $hex)));  

    return $decimal;
}

foreach(array('0X1.FAP+9', '0X1.C4P+9', '0X1.F3P+9', '0X1.05P+10', '0X1P+0') as $hex) {
    var_dump(strtod($hex));
};
```

Comment: wow, really thank you for your reply  and also your answer is right(i tried it on http://codepad.viper-7.com/DVEfjh) but my php version is 5.2.17 so i got " syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION"，Can you help me to fixed it?I'm a freshman to php

Comment: Why do you have such an old and outdated version of PHP?

Comment: there is a bug in your code.   0X1P+0  the value is 1,but use your code ,i got 0

Comment: Yeah, I assumed all numbers will be decimal (requiring a '.'). Adjusted the regex in the code.

Comment: oo.. i got a new problem.  0X1.95810624DD2F2P-4 is 0.099000 but use your solution,i got 3.168. can you help me to fix this again?

Comment: i solved it myself,yes i really can write a piece of php code now. LOL  thank you very much  @silkfire

Answer (score 0):

`hexdec(0X1.05P+10)`

OK so that looks wrong to me as that doesn't look like a proper hex number but its the hexdec() function you want in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

```
echo hexdec("0X1FAP")+9
echo hexdec("0X1C4P")+9
echo hexdec("0X1F3P")+9
echo hexdec("0X105P")+10
```

> decimal = hex
>       (1044.0)<sub>10</sub> = (414)<sub>16</sub>

Comment: yes i tried this method, but it seemed not work right. the result is different from the result of strtod.

Comment: That isn't a valid HEX input and even if we assume it is it isn't equivilent to 1044.0. 0X1.FAP+9 for example is 1.978759765625

Comment: man strtod found:       A  hexadecimal  number  consists  of a ''0x'' or ''0X'' followed by a nonempty sequence of hexadecimal digits possibly containing a
       radix character, optionally followed by a binary exponent. A binary exponent consists of a ''P'' or ''p'', followed by an  optional
       plus or minus sign, followed by a non-empty sequence of decimal digits, and indicates multiplication by a power of 2.  At least one
       of radix character and binary exponent must be present.

Comment: Thats specific to strtod then I assume as its not standard format the 0x1 = 1 is but the full structure isn't.  easy test go on google find a hex to decimal converter or decimal to hex and put in your 1044.0 and your string and see what they output.